# Do whales really sleep "head down"?

Tags: physiology, sleep, vertebrates

Currently there is a broadcast in German TV (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Swarm_(TV_series)) where there was a scene of multiple whales sleeping in suspended state, vertically heads down.
The whales were not moving any fins.

The scene looked impressive, but I wonder:
The lungs had some air inside, and when being in suspended state the other parts of the body must have a tendency to sink, as otherwise the whale would surface (by the rules of physics).
Assuming that the lungs are in the front part of the body, I'd assume that that part of the body would have a tendency to surface, while the tail has a tendency to sink (submerge).

So the scene in the film was just opposite to my expectations.
Thus my question: Was the scene real, or was it just artistic fiction?

Comment: Welcome to the site. What research have you done on your own to answer this question? The Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Our goal is not simply to be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way.

Comment: Well, the best resource that I could find (https://marinepath.com/why-do-sperm-whales-sleep-vertically/) was that sperm whales do sleep vertically, but the text did not mention whether "head up" or "head down".